# Why is there zero holonomy around a geodesic?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading about the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, and in the beginning of the section I'm studying I saw:

[image]
Why is this true? I know this should be trivial but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: The cited paragraphs make very little sense. What book are you reading?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: the book is "A first course in curves and surfaces", from Ted Shifrin. Page 79 here http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf

Comment: In fairness, I was rather misquoted.

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry, I fixed it now.

Comment: Now the claim is clearly true and you should try to write a proof yourself starting with formalization of the notion "turns relative to the given framing".

Comment: @MoisheKohan The angle between parallel vector fields is constant and if $\alpha$ is a geodesic then $\alpha'(t)$ is a parallel vector field. So if $v$ is tangent to $\alpha$, $\langle \alpha'(t), v \rangle$ is constant. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, because it is zero.